# Symfony 2.8 security setup with LightSamlPhp Bundle - Multiple Login Methods

Tags: php, symfony, saml, symfony-security

I am running into an issue with setting up Authentication in Symfony 2.8 with Saml plugin (https://www.lightsaml.com/SP-Bundle/Getting-started/).
Problem:
I want to able to login via SAML and via going to admin page. The /admin/login page works fine, I see the user authenticated from the database. However, when I try to go through the Saml process, I always land on the /discovery page. When I see the logs, I do user is authenticated. So, I think I have something not correctly in security settings. Please let me know if you can help

Here are the settings from

### config/security.yml file:

firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

```
    login_firewall:
        pattern: ^/saml/login$
        anonymous: ~
    discovery_firewall:
        pattern: ^/saml/discovery$
        anonymous: ~

    secured_area:
        pattern:   ^/
        anonymous: ~
        light_saml_sp:
            provider: db_provider    # user provider name configured in step 9
            #user_creator: user_creator  # name of the user creator service created in step 10
            login_path: /saml/login
            check_path: /saml/login_check
            default_target_path: /profile

        form_login:
            login_path: /admin/login
            check_path: /admin/login_check
            default_target_path: /
            remember_me: true
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /


        # activate different ways to authenticate

        # http_basic: ~
        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate

        # form_login: ~
        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html

access_control:
    - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }        
    - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Comment: I don't know why you need the discovery firewall, but it is listed on the 2nd position in you security file. That is why it stops on discovery. Perhaps it needs to be anonymous: true.

Comment: Hi Duro - If do not have the firewall for discovery page. I land on the discovery page with too many redirects error. This is the error I see on dev console: net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: Did you try the security setup as in 'getting started'?  Does that work?

Comment: Yes, with saml stuff, I can login just fine. I want users to login via saml and via direct login method. The saml authentication does authenticate the user as I can see from logs, but somehow the page goes into infinite redirects. So, I think it is something with Symfony security settings.